# Continue pipeline flow after a sink

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-data-fusion

I need to load a CSV file located in GCS in a Cloud SQL database(postgres) using Data Fusion.

For each CSV line i need to insert a line in another table (Table_B) and reference it in my destination table (Table_A) with the inserted PK.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to continue the pipeline flow after a sink? Im not able to add a connector after Database Sink.
2. Is it possible to return the inserted pk in Database sink plugin?

Screenshots:
[Data Fusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZVFP.png)

Comment: What would you like to add after specifying the sink node? Is that Save_Account?

Comment: I want to add a connector between Save_Account and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an action plugin after your sink. For example, [Database Action](https://github.com/cdapio/hydrator-plugins/blob/release/2.3/database-plugins/docs/Database-action.md) can be used to run SQL commands after your pipeline writes data to the sink.

Action plugins can be found under the Conditions and Actions section in Pipeline Studio.

You can write your own action plugin using [this](https://github.com/data-integrations/example-action) as a starting point if the existing action plugins don't meet your needs.